# How to safe modal popup position when you have scrolled down page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

Hi i have this HTMLC/CSS/JS site: [site link](http://webmode.lt/modal/)

Click on first icon named "CRYSTALLINE", the modal shows up.

When i scroll down page, and click on icon to show popup, its takes my on top of page..
How to safe your scrolling position on site when opening this popup?

Comment: Use `preventDefault()` on your function. Also add your relevant code in the question

Comment: I dont now exactly wich part of code does those actions.

Comment: Apparently a function here http://webmode.lt/modal/js/modalEffects.js ? Why you don't know isn't your code?

Comment: The code is from web. I have noticed if i delete  href="#" from modal trigger them modal stays at scroll position

Comment: Of course that's what the `#` does in the href but you can prevent this with the preventdefault

Comment: So in which place at modalEffects.js i need to do preventdefault?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is actually your question, but you can always get current top scroll position using `$(document).scrollTop();`
or the pure JS `document.documentElement.scrollTop`